# Gray exclamation mark keeps appearing on YouTube

Tags: youtube, flash

This has been happening a **lot** lately, mostly on YouTube. I don't know if it's YouTube, Adobe Flash or Firefox:
[image: Gray exclamation mark]

This will happen even half-way through playing a video, it will randomly turn into this image. I have to restart Firefox to continue to play YouTube videos.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Firefox & the Flash plug-in? Does it happen just on Firefox or all browsers? Just on YouTube or other sites too?

Comment: Is there a tooltip when you hover over the exclamation mark?

Comment: @Barry latest version of Firefox and Flash as far as I know. I try to keep up to date.

Answer (score 1):

It is accused of being a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547548/flex-error-white-exclamation-point-in-gray-circle-what-does-it-mean) (of certain versions of Flash Player) and an out of memory notification.

[Adobe Forums: Gray circle with white exclamation mark on white background](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/693187?tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

It's your Adobe Flash.

Try restarting your browser. Then go back to youtube.com and try to update your Java/Adobe/default Flash program.

Comment: It happens to me across multiple PCs, OSes, and browsers. It also happens whether I'm using html5 or flash for youtube. I don't want to flat out call you wrong, but I'm quite sure you are.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's Firefox. This happened to me on Google Chrome, and the grey excalimation mark  happened on YouTube, and another site I was watching an anime on. I tried YouTube on Internet Explorer, and it works fine.

I suggest uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If it's happening across platforms and regardles of video accelerator than it is clearly a YouTube problem and not specific to one's PC or OS.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's Adobe Flash as others have stated. If restarting doesn't help I suggest switching to HTML5 on YouTube. You can do this by following the following link:
http://www.youtube.com/html5

Good Luck!